# Как сделать так, чтобы из буфера выводился русский текст?

Tags: c++

Знаю, тема обыденная, да не смог сетом локейтом заставить выводить скопированный в буфер текст в консольное окно... Причем английский текст выводится нормально. В чем проблема? Как быть? Спасибо.

Comment: Вообщем-то вопрос больше сводится к тому, как из буфера получить данные в нормальном "виде"...

Comment: А какой у вас компилятор? Если VC++, то попробуйте зайти в Свойства проекта -> Общие -> Набор символов -> Использовать многобайтовую кодировку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  if( OpenClipboard(NULL) )
    {
      char* data = (char*)GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
      if(data) {
    ;//делай что хочешь с данными, например - выводи на консоль
    if (isatty(fileno(stdout))) {
      printf ("recode\n");
      CharToOem(data,data);
    }
    printf ("data: <%s>\n",data);
      }
      CloseClipboard();

    }
```

Например так.

Comment: VS 2010 ругается на isatty и на error C2664: 'CharToOemW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'LPCWSTR'

Comment: Спасибо, сделал....